# tidyr: transpose variables and fill blanks with zeros

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like so:

```
set.seed(456)
df <- data.frame(site = c(rep("Site1", 10), rep("Site2", 9)), 
                 genus = c(rep("sp1", 5), rep("sp2", 5), rep("sp1", 5), rep("sp2", 2), rep("sp3", 2)), 
                 abun = rnorm(19, 10,1))
```

I need to make a dataframe that converts the levels of the factor `site` to variables. Thus, `site1` and  `site2` would become a variable and the data in those variables would be the `abun` values for `genus` levels at those sites. Since not all sites will have the same `genus` or the same number of individuals from that genus, those sites without a species or with few representatives of those species would be filled in with zeros.

The data in this example would appear as:

```
output<- data.frame(genus = c(rep("sp1", 5), rep("sp2", 5), rep("sp3", 2)), 
                    site1 = c(9,22,74,86,79, 34,9,29,24,39,0,0), 
                    site2 = c(38,22,76,83,60, 66,85,0,0,0, 46,72))
```

I have tried various versions of tidyverse mutate or reshape functions, and cannot get the desired output nor do I know how to get the zeros to fill in the empty data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the indices to be parallel in each group, set up an index for each, which you can do with `dplyr::group_by` and `row_number`, after which spreading will work properly:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(456)

df<- data.frame( site= c(rep("Site1", 10), rep("Site2", 9)), 
                 genus= c(rep("sp1", 5), rep("sp2", 5), rep("sp1", 5), rep("sp2", 2), rep("sp3", 2) ), 
                 abun= rnorm(19, 10,1))

df %>% 
    group_by(site) %>% 
    mutate(i = row_number()) %>%    # add row indices for each group
    spread(site, abun, fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>     genus     i     Site1     Site2
#>  * <fctr> <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1    sp1     1  8.656479  9.084189
#>  2    sp1     2 10.621776 11.311097
#>  3    sp1     3 10.800875 10.988726
#>  4    sp1     4  8.611108 11.653929
#>  5    sp1     5  9.285643  8.559195
#>  6    sp2     6  9.675939 11.947356
#>  7    sp2     7 10.690643 11.736936
#>  8    sp2     8 10.250548  0.000000
#>  9    sp2     9 11.007352  0.000000
#> 10    sp2    10 10.573235  0.000000
#> 11    sp3     8  0.000000 10.387483
#> 12    sp3     9  0.000000 12.280034
```

If you have multiple values for a given `i` and `genus`, this will fail, and you'll have to make a more unique identifier column.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 No, that gives you a different data.frame with the same amount of rows as `df` (19), not the 12 of `output`.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. The one trouble I had, but was able to solve in an inefficient way, was the issue with the `Site1` and `Site2` variables becoming factors, the fill=0 didn't work. So I used the as.numeric function on each variable and changed all NAs to 0. is there a way to fix this in the tidyr functions?

Comment: Really the best way is to avoid making them factors beforehand (with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv`, if that's the source). If they're factors of numbers, be particularly careful; `as.numeric(factor(2:3))` will return `1:2` because that's what the values are stored as underneath, so you've got to do `as.numeric(as.character(factor(2:3)))`.